# Dynamic Event Listener Working only on the Last Created Element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to add event listeners to a bunch of dynamically created divs, but for some reason it only work in the last created div.
How to make the event listener work in all divs?

**Update**

```
 for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) 
{
   row_string =  row_string+  "<div id='row" + i + "' class='detail-view'></div>";
   document.getElementById('window').innerHTML = document.getElementById('window').innerHTML+row_string;
   document.getElementById('row'+i).addEventListener('click', function() {openRow("#row"+i)});
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show how are you adding the event listeners?

Comment: Sure, I'll update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are modifying `innerHTML` of the wrapper element. After modification the `innerHTML` is parsed and the new Nodes are generated. Since the old Nodes are replaced with the new Nodes, the event listeners that had been bound to the (now deleted) elements in the previous iterations won't work.

You should either use the event delegation technique or generate the elements using `document.createElement` method and append them using the `.appendChild` of the wrapper element (the `#window` element).

Here is an example of the second suggested method:

```
function openRow(event) {
  var id = this.id;
  // ...
}

var el, win = document.getElementById('window');

for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) 
{
   el = document.createElement('div');
   el.classList.add('detail-view');
   el.id = 'row_' + i;
   el.addEventListener('click', openRow);
   win.appendChild(el);
}
```

Comment: I have to use document.createElement to create all divs needed and use appendChild to add then to the pafe. Once created I'll use the addEventListener right?

Comment: @MarcelOliveira Yes.  I'll update the answer with an example.

Comment: Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @MarcelOliveira You are welcome, I have updated the answer.

Comment: I'm now converting my code to the createElement stuff, as soon as I finish I'll let you know if it worked or not. Thanks

Comment: Hello Vohuman, I've finished changing my code, and it haven't worked. I've created some local variables to store my strucures, like, row. I'm now adding to a row a id, based in a global variable called total. When I run  `row.id = "row"+total_Tests;` and `row.addEventListener('click', function() {openRow('#'+row.id)});` all the rows have the same ID, do you know that's wrong? the total variable is increased in each new row added.

Comment: @Ram You had mentioned that "the event listeners that had been bound to the (now deleted) elements in the previous iterations won't work.".
But when new nodes are generated, they will be attached with new event listeners just like the first time, and such new listeners should work is it? Thanks.

Comment: @ar3 Yes, if you bind a handler for an event that is triggered by a new element it will work. OP is using `innerHTML` which is destructive way of changing content of an element. It parses string representation of dom elements and generates new elements accordingly. The result before and after setting `innerHTML` might be similar but you will end up having new DOM elements that have no event handlers bound to them.

Comment: Got it Ram. Thanks. One last thing, when it reparses, will it not also re-add event listeners to every old element. I'm learning JS and my idea is that innerHTML goes through the for loop every time there is a change. So, when it iterates, it also re-attaches event listeners.

Comment: @ar3 That's not correct. Unless the code snippet has DOM event attributes (like `onclick` attribute), browser won't bind any event handlers to the new elements. One needs to select the new elements and bind event handlers to them. Just like the way the code snippet in my answer shows. It generates a new element and binds a new event handler by using `addEventListener` for each element. You are can either add event listener after or before appending the element.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but it looks like you're setting the ID  of your div element equal to i, and not '#row' + i.

Also, this is an instance where jQuery would help immensely.  Not to be that guy, but you could very easily just do

```
    $('.detail-view').click(function() { /* code */ });
```

**Edit**  Anyways, your problem here is function scope in javascript.  i will always = total in your case, even after the for loop executes.  I created a closure for this.

Check out this jsfiddle.  https://jsfiddle.net/jr9gzvda/

Comment: Ops, sorry, my code isn't exactly this one, I've wrote the ID wrongly I'll correct it.